# SFDX meta data deployment issue for existing apex component update

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, visualforce-component

We have an issue to deploy apex components updates with new or removed attributes, or controller class variable updates.

When deploying the component together with related apex pages, `sfdx force:source:deploy` is stating an error saying the attributes doesn't exist, although it is not referenced anymore on the component.

This is an example of error we have
[image: Example]

The error seems to be a known issue at Salesforce, but not fixed ⇒
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001lzXwQAI&title=metadata-deployment-is-failing-for-vf-component-with-an-error-unsupported-attributes

Comment: Have you tried the workaround suggested by them?

Comment: A common solution to similar issues is to do two deployments; the first removes all usages of the attribute(s) in question and the second removes the attribute(s) themselves.

Comment: Thanks you for your comments,

This is indeed how we ended up deploying, but it's not a good solution. Especially for production, where you'll have to break your org during the execution of the test classes...